# #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, alias

I am running this query

```
SELECT *  
FROM (`T_INV_DTL`)  
LEFT JOIN 
 (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT T_INV_INVESTIGATOR.Employee_id) AS Employee_id
  FROM T_INV_INVESTIGATOR
  GROUP BY  `T_INV_INVESTIGATOR`.`inv_dtl_id`
  ) ON  `T_INV_DTL`.`inv_dtl_id` =  `T_INV_INVESTIGATOR`.`inv_dtl_id`
JOIN  `T_INVESTIGATION` ON  `T_INV_DTL`.`inv_id` =  `T_INVESTIGATION`.`inv_id`
```

and it is giving this error:

**#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias**

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give an alias to subquery,

Check this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T_INV_DTL T  
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT inv_dtl_id , GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Employee_id ) AS Employee_id 
            FROM T_INV_INVESTIGATOR 
            GROUP BY inv_dtl_id ) A ON T.inv_dtl_id = A.inv_dtl_id 
JOIN T_INVESTIGATION TI ON T.inv_id = TI.inv_id
```

Comment: Now I get error this "#1054 - Unknown column 'A.inv_dtl_id' in 'on clause'"

Comment: @user1971825 Try now I have updated my answer. You have select that field in select query also.

Comment: Hello.. Its good.. Can you change this query to codeigniter sql query?

Comment: I haven't worked with codeigniter so sorry about that. Welcome to Stack overflow, If you find this answer helps you than you can accept the answer by clicking on right tick so community can trust you..

Answer (score 0):

when ever you write a sub query you must give an alias for the whlole

and

if you have more than one query then better to give different name in the select lists using alias to avoid conflicts